# Generate all combinations from list of characters

Tags: perl

I am busy implementing a lab for pen testers to create MD5 hashes from 4 letter words. I need the words to have a combination of lower and uppercase letters as well as numeric and special characters, but I just do not seem to find out how to combine any given characters in all orders. So currently I have this:

```
my $str = 'aaaa';
print $str++, $/ while $str le 'dddd';
```

Which will do:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
...
...
dddd
```

There is no way however how I can make it do:

```
Aaaa
AAaa
aAaa
...
dddD
```

Not even to mention adding numbers and special characters. What I really wanted to do was to make the characters to create words based on a given list. So if I feel I want to use `abeDod@#` it should create all combinations from those characters.

Edit to clarify.

Let's say I give the characters `aBc#` I need it to give it a a count to say it must have maximum of 4 letters per word and with combination of all the given characters, like:

```
aBc#
Bac#
caB#
#Bca
...
```

I hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: "_lower and uppercase letters as well as numeric and special characters_"  -- are you saying that you want each 4-letter word to have one of each of these?  (So `a1B#` but not `a1B7` since this one doesn't have a special character.)  Or is it ok to have `abcd`, `1234` (etc) among others?

Comment: @zdim, no, so all combinations of a given set. Let me edit and clarify.

Comment: OK, thank you.  posted one way for what I think you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list of integers that are [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the characters you accept, to sample from it using your favorite (pseudo-)random number generator. Then convert each to its character using [chr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) and concatenate them.

Like

```
perl -wE'$rw .= chr( 32+(int rand 126-32) ) for 1..4; say $rw'
```

Notes

- I use a one-liner merely for easy copy-paste testing. Write this nicely in a  script, please
- I use the sketchy [rand](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html), good for shuffling things a bit.  Replace with a better one if needed
- Glueing four (pseudo-)random numbers *does not* build a good distribution; even as each letter on its own does, the whole thing does not. But the four should satisfy most needs.

  If not, I think that you'd need to produce a far longer list (range of allowed chars repeated four times perhaps) and randomize it, then draw four-letter subsequences. A lot more work
- I need to tap dance a little to produce (random-ish) integers from 32 to 126 using `rand`, since it takes only the end of range.  Also, this takes all of them from that range, likely not what you want; so specify subranges, or specific lists that you want to draw from

Comment: Thanks a mill. This does exactly what I asked, but I just realized I asked incorrectly So I am going to ask another question, regarless, this does exactly what I required from this question.