# Generate word from list of characters

Tags: perl

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851453/generate-all-combinations-from-list-of-characters) and I realized I was asking the question incorrectly, though the answer @Zdim provided is exactly what I asked: So now I need to change that question a bit.

```
my $str = 'aaaa';
print $str++, $/ while $str le 'dddd';
```

So the above code does each combination from `aaaa` to `dddd` for instance:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
...
daaa
...
dddd
```

However, we need to generate **all** the possible combinations of a given set of the given characters. whether they are numeric, special characters or alphabetical characters. So If I tell the script the minimum `2` and maximum is `4` letter words and I give an input string of:

```
abcdefG1234%#@
```

it will then generate:

```
aa
aaa
aaaa
bb
aaab
bbbb
@@@@
abc@
ab@1
...
```

So it should use each of the characters and create each possible combination from minimum `2` characters to maximum `4` characters.

So even if I give the entire alphanumeric and special characters, it will create each possible word or string within the range of `2` to `4` characters.

If We take this `glob` example, it is close, but it will only do all the sets of 4, not all combinations from `2`, then `3` and then `4`

```
print, while glob '{A,B,C,D,#,@,a,d,e,f}'x4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for my $i (2..4) {
   say while glob '{A,B,C,D,#,@,a,d,e,f}' x $i;
}
```

Comment: Dammit.. why did I not think of that, I am actually using the exact `for (1..10) {print $_` for something else in this exact same script for something else..

Comment: Would you know if there is a limit for the number of characters I can place? If I `while (glob '{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}' x $i...` it seems to stop at the end of `2` characters being `ZZ`, no matter what the range is.

Comment: It doesn't stop; only pauses. (2s in my case.) It seems that `glob` generates a list of the all the results it's going to return up front. If it pauses for a very long time, it might be that you've run out of memory and started thrashing. See `NestedLoop` from the [Algorithm::Loop](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Loops) if you need to cut down on memory.

Comment: I see, Thanks a mill again.

Answer (score 4):

One way for this is to use a little extension of the linked question and answer. To generate the sequence of ascii codes which will be sampled from, from a given string

```
perl -wE'say for map { ord($_) } split "", q(abcdefG1234%#@)'
```

Now with that list on hand, run the code from the linked page for sequences of length 2 through 4.